# Get List if Properties of type ICollection from Generic Class

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have an object that contains some ICollection type properties

So basically the class looks like this:

```
Class Employee {

public ICollection<Address> Addresses {get;set;}

public ICollection<Performance> Performances {get; set;}

}
```

The problem is get property names of type ICollection, inside of Generic class,  by using reflection.

My Generic Class is

```
Class CRUD<TEntity>  {

public object Get() {
 var properties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().Where(m=m.GetType() == typeof(ICollection ) ... 
}
```

But it is not working.

How can I get a property here?

Comment: is the code compiling ?? because you have missed `>` operator in lamda expression

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`GetProperties()` returns a `PropertyInfo[]`. You then do a `Where` using `m.GetType()`. If we assume that you missed a `>`, and this is `m=>m.GetType()`, then you are actually saying:

```
 typeof(PropertyInfo) == typeof(ICollection)
```

(caveat: actually, it is probably a `RuntimePropertyInfo`, etc)

What you *mean* is probably:

```
typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(m.PropertyType)
```

However! Note that `ICollection` <> `ICollection<>` <> `ICollection<Address>` etc - so it isn't even that easy. You might need:

```
m.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
    m.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
```

Confirmed; this works:

```
static void Main()
{
    Foo<Employee>();
}
static void Foo<TEntity>() {
    var properties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().Where(m =>
        m.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&
        m.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)
    ).ToArray();
    // ^^^ contains Addresses and Performances
}
```

Comment: Thank you Marc, it works! Yes indeed I was getting RuntimePropertyInfo and I did exactly what you did but I don't know why it is different and probably because I was comparing with ICollection!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IsGenericType` and  check `GetGenericTypeDefinition` against `typeof(ICollection<>)`

```
public object Get()
{
    var properties =
        typeof (TEntity).GetProperties()
            .Where(m => m.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
                    m.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (ICollection<>));
}
```